# Haskell split, intercalate and lists

Tags: list, haskell, text, types

I am trying to split a `Data.Text` into a `[Text]`, run a function to the elements of that list, then `unword` them, or `intercalate` them. But the types do not match. Instead of a `Text -> Text` I get a `[Text] -> [Text]` function.

```
import Data.Text(Text, pack, unpack, intercalate, split)
f = split (\x-> x==' ') . intercalate (pack " ")
:t f 
--Prints for some reason: f :: [Text] -> [Text]

g = split (\x-> x==' ') . Data.Text.unwords
:t g
-- Prints again: g :: [Text] -> [Text]
```

How can I get a `Text -> Text` function?

Comment: The order is wrong, try: `intercalate (pack " ") . split (\x -> x == ' ')`.

Comment: `a . b` is `\x -> a (b x)`, hence `b` is applied first, then `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your functions is:

```
split :: (Char -> Bool) -> Text -> [Text]
intercalate :: Text -> [Text] -> Text
```

If you were to write it without function composition the code would look like:

```
f :: Text -> Text
f text = intercalate (pack " ") (split (==' ') text)
-- or also: intercalate (pack " ") $ split (==' ') text
```

So what you want to do first is splitting and then intercalating. Look at how function composition is defined:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

It takes two functions `f` and `g` and returns a function `f(g(x))` applying first `g` and then `f`. So, when you write

```
f = split (\x-> x==' ') . intercalate (pack " ")
```

what you would get is:

```
f :: [Text] -> [Text]
f = \x -> intercalate (pack " ") (split (==' ') x)
-- first splitting and then intercalating
```

The code you want is:

```
f :: Text -> Text 
f = intercalate (pack " ") . split (== ' ')
-- equivalent to:
-- f = \x -> intercalate (pack " ") (split (== ' ') x)
-- where you first split and then intercalate
```